# What was the name of the fail-safe device that 7 of 9 had in her brain?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

What was the name of the fail safe device that limited the range of emotions in 7 of 9? Was it the cortical node or cortical inhibitor? I found this [page](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Cortical_node) but it doesn't say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was her **[cortical node](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Cortical_node).** A [cortical inhibitor](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Cortical_inhibitor) (not the same thing) is a medical device that suppresses theta wave mental activity in order to prevent certain kinds of telepathic damage.

The episode you're referring to is VOY: "[Human error](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/715.htm)".

> **EMH:** *Is it that obvious? I've completed my diagnostic. What you experienced was no malfunction. **Your cortical node was designed to
>   shut down your higher brain functions when you achieve a certain level
>   of emotional stimulation.***
>
> **SEVEN:** *Clarify.*
>
> **EMH:** *It appears to be a fail-safe mechanism to deactivate drones who start to regain their emotions. Knowing the Borg, it makes perfect
>   sense. Finding one's heart is the surest road to individuality.*

Brannon Braga had this to say on the subject:

> "It was my feeling that Seven Of Nine should have died. If you watch
>   the episode ‘Human Error’ written by Andre Bormanis, it was not only a
>   heart breaking episode in that **Seven Of Nine learns, as she begins
>   to explore her human emotions, that she can’t experience them. There’s
>   a Borg chip inside her that will kill her if she tries to do so.**
>   First of all, that’s kind of an interesting ‘rape victim’ analogy or
>   whatever you want to call it, about a damaged woman who can’t get past
>   what happened to her, but I also always saw it as a crucial episode
>   that would set up the finale.
>
> "This was a woman who knew she was neither here nor there. She
>   couldn’t go back to the Borg, nor would she want to, but she could
>   never be fully human, so she was doomed. And I wanted to have her
>   sacrifice herself to get her shipmates home."